# Image quantization with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, quantization

I wanted to have a look at the example code for image quantization from [here](https://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2012/07/color-quantization.html)
However, it's rather old and Python and NP have changed since then.

```
from pylab import imread,imshow,figure,show,subplot
from numpy import reshape,uint8,flipud
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans,vq

img = imread('clearsky.jpg')

# reshaping the pixels matrix
pixel = reshape(img,(img.shape[0]*img.shape[1],3))

# performing the clustering
# print(type(pixel))
centroids,_ = kmeans(pixel,6) # six colors will be found
# quantization
qnt,_ = vq(pixel,centroids)

# reshaping the result of the quantization
centers_idx = reshape(qnt,(img.shape[0],img.shape[1]))
clustered = centroids[centers_idx]

figure(1)
subplot(211)
imshow(flipud(img))
subplot(212)
imshow(flipud(clustered))
show()
```

It's falling over at line 12 `centroids,_ = kmeans(pixel,6)`

File "D:\Python30\lib\site-packages\scipy\cluster\vq.py", line 454, in kmeans
book, dist = _kmeans(obs, guess, thresh=thresh)
File "D:\Python30\lib\site-packages\scipy\cluster\vq.py", line 309, in _kmeans
code_book.shape[0])
File "_vq.pyx", line 340, in scipy.cluster._vq.update_cluster_means
TypeError: type other than float or double not supported

I can change 6 to 6.0, but confused as what to do for the NParray passing into kmeans.

What do I need to do to update the code to get the example up and running?

Comment: @DataSciRookie - that was a fast response! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to Convert Image Pixels to Floating Point: Before passing the pixels to kmeans, convert them to a floating-point type to ensure compatibility:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans, vq

# Reading the image
img = plt.imread('clearsky.jpg')

# Convert image pixels to float
pixel = np.reshape(img, (img.shape[0]*img.shape[1], 3)).astype(float)

# Performing the clustering
centroids, _ = kmeans(pixel, 6.0)  # six colors will be found

# Quantization
qnt, _ = vq(pixel, centroids)

# Reshaping the result of the quantization
centers_idx = np.reshape(qnt, (img.shape[0], img.shape[1]))
clustered = centroids[centers_idx.astype(int)]

# Displaying the original and quantized images
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.title('Original Image')

plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(clustered.astype(np.uint8))
plt.title('Quantized Image')
plt.show()
```